# Get data from specific condition in array react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Well, let's go in parts ... I have an array called orderForm from my cart and get this:

```
0: 
    attachmentOfferings: []
    attachments: []
    availability: "available"
    bundleItems: []
    id: "38811"
    listPrice: 34900
    productCategories: 
     84: "Panties"
     157: "shorts"
     [[Prototype]]: Object
1: 
    attachmentOfferings: []
    attachments: []
    availability: "available"
    bundleItems: []
    id: "33611"
    listPrice: 39900
    productCategories: 
        85: "Tops"
        157: "long"
        [[Prototype]]: Object
```

At this moment I itinirate and get all the products selecting `productCategories` key
with the code below:

```
const mediaTypes = orderForm.items
    .map(dataItem => dataItem.productCategories)
    .filter((mediaType, index, array) => array.indexOf(mediaType) === index);
```

and the result:

```
[
    {
        "84": "Panties",
        "157": "shorts"
    },
    {
        "84": "Panties",
        "158": "Briefs"
    },
    {
        "85": "Tops",
        "187": "long"
    }
]
```

But until here I don't know how can I obtain just only the products that are "Panties" and their price are under 699

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use something like:

```js
orderForm.items
    .map(item => [item.listPrice, Object.values(item.productCategories)])
    .filter(([price, categories]) => price < 699 && categories.indexOf("Panties") > -1)
```